# What's the purpose of using classes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, constructor

I mostly see JavaScript use classes as a constructor as following:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  // Getter
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }
  // Method
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

What's the reason React uses classes without using the `contructor()` function, such as following?  I don't see classes being used to create instances.

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app-content">
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Add breakpoints to React.Component and this class including a constructor and step through line by line to really see what is happening in detail including how the extends is effecting the compilation and execution. There is a lot happening behind the scenes to render even this simple component. It goes beyond just    the presence of a constructor not. Also try adding a constructor with initial state and see the effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the reason React uses classes without using the `contructor()` function

From the `JavaScript` class [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor#Description):

> If you do not specify a constructor method, a default constructor is used.

So a `constructor` exists for every `class` whether a constructor method is specified or not.

---

> I don't see classes being used to create instances.

`React` components implemented as classes **get instantiated by `React`** as part of the rendering process.

Specifically, in the new [`React Fiber`](https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture) creating an instance of a `React` class component happens on [this line of the source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a129259ad6a61790fe1912a87cb45018d942f90c/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L555).

---

But yes, @vicondin is right that the simple component from the question can be implemented as a [function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), that class components used to be the only way to maintain state, implement lifecycle methods, etc., and that the new [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) makes it possible to...

> use state and other React features without writing a class.

Comment: "So a constructor exists for every class whether a constructor method is specified or not." Interesting.  I wonder if we ever have to use `constructor()` then. I'm thinkg `extends` probably brings over the constructor function?

Comment: @Kevvv exactly.  You only need to provide a `constructor` function if there is something specific you need to do in the `constructor` (like set the initial `state`, `bind` methods, etc.).

Answer (score 12):

Right now you should use classes in React if you need to use "advanced" component lifecycle methods like `shouldComponentUpdate()` or such.

Previously class components were used to handle local state in them. Right now we have [Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) which allows to use state in a more elegant way and without need of class components.

If you want more details, you can read the article by Dan Abramov: [How Are Function Components Different from Classes?](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/).

Regardless your example, you're right, this code:

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app-content">
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

can be written as:

```
function App() {
  return <div className="app-content"></div>
}
```

Comment: I feel like the main reason behind using `class` was to inherit methods, but this could've been done with `require`

Answer (score 1):

In React, state is used in a React class component. There you can set initial state in the constructor of the class, but also access and update it with `this.state` and `this.setState`, because you have access to the class instance by using the `this` object.

If you use class in React component,  even without using `constructor()` you can set initial state like below:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    hello: 'Hello'
  };

  onClickHello = value => {
    this.setState({ hello: 'Why did you clicked?' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-content" onClick={this.onClickHello}>
        {this.state.hello}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Another advantage is you can make use of all the [React lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Update: After React16, you can use the lifecycle events even in function components using react [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: So class is being used in React so that the state could be accessed and updated?

Comment: Nope. You can make use of other class functionalities like `this`, lifecycle methods. Updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Also biggest reason is the handling of state and lifecycle(componendDidMount ..etc) , class can do everything functions can , but at the cost of readability and statelessness . But in the most cases I rarely use classes only if I need a complex parent component with lifecycle